# How to add a button that translates the page into one language automatically without having to select from a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, blogger, google-translate

How to add a button that translates the page into one language automatically without having to select from a drop down menu? I'm using blogger platform.

Comment: blogger have widget for that

Comment: blogger have widget for that

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered a way to do this without a script -

```
<a expr:href='"https://translate.google.com/translate?u=" + data:post.url + "&amp;sl=language-code&amp;tl=language-code"'>Translate</a>
```

sl = language code used in the website
tl = language code of the language of intended translation